# Include an Element Inside Current HTML with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to include an element inside current HTML with Thymeleaf something like:

```
<span id="el">Rouro</span>
<h2 th:text="|${elo.mimo} nakuru: |" th:include="this :: el"> --- </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exact answer to your question but desired functionality could be achieved by following code:

```
<span id="el">Rouro</span>
<h2><th:block th:text="|${elo.mimo} nakuru: |" /><th:block th:include="this :: el" /></h2>
```